# What's the proper way to access extraFiles or extraResources using electron-builder?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

What's the proper way to make this code work universally in dev mode and in compiled/packaged mode on all platform?

```
  const log = (string) => {
    console.log(string)
    mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(`console.log('${string}')`)
  }
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  // works in mac os packaged app only
  log(process.resourcesPath)
  log(fs.readdirSync(process.resourcesPath))
  log(fs.readdirSync(path.join(process.resourcesPath, 'static')))

  // works in node dev only
  log(__dirname)
  log(fs.readdirSync(__dirname))
  log(fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, 'static')))

  // haven't tested on windows
```

Answer (score 3):

```
const resourcePath =
  !process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
    ? process.resourcesPath // Live Mode
    : __dirname; // Dev Mode

const staticPath = path.join(resourcePath, 'static');
```